# Sending email to multiple users using form to mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Good morning. I have a form where I used the form to mail function, everything works fine but when I add another email it doesn't work. Here's a sample of the code I did:

```js
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name', 'referralname', 'email', 'phonenumber'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->attachFiles(['image']);


$pp->sendEmailTo('email@email.com', 'email@email.com', 'email@email.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: `sendEmailTo` is not a core php function, so we would need to see it to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to pass the email addresses as array.

```
$pp->sendEmailTo(['someone@gmail.com', 'another@gmail.com','more@gmail.com']);
```

See http://reusableforms.com/doc/customization

Answer (score 1):

You would better make an array of all emails and then use a for loop for mailing.like below :

```
$myarr = array('email@email.com', 'email@email.com', 'email@email.com');
for($i = 0;count($myarr)>$i;$i++){
$pp->sendEmailTo($myarr[$i]);
}
```

I also recommend you to set error_reporting on so that you can debug easier